# Trying to find a quick way to read a custom "configuration"

Tags: python

I'm trying a find a smooth way to read that file like "json" in python but it's kinda weird (I tried to convert it but not possible

```
return {
    ["gradient"] = true,
    ["dark"] = true,
    ["sky"] = false,
    ["rainbow"] = false,
    ["settings"] = {
        ["size"] = 100,
        ["smooth"] = true,
        ["dev"] = {
            ["inspect"] = "F1"
        }
        ["logo_size"] = 600
    },
    ["jokes"] = false,
}
```

`

tried to make that code but receiving all time errors and not manage to read it

```
import ast

with open('file.ini') as f:
  data_str = f.read()
  
data_str = data_str.replace('["', '"') .replace('"]', '"').replace("return ", "").replace("=", ":")
                   
data = ast.literal_eval(data_str)

true_values = []

for k, v in data.items():
  if v == True:   
    true_values.append(k)
    
print(true_values)
```

Comment: So you're trying to read a file that has the contents shown in the first code block, and load it as a Python dictionary?

Comment: yeah @SmallPepperZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```py
def parse(iterator, data):
    # Use a `iterator` to read each line on demand
    while True:
        try:
            line = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.rstrip(',')

        # The end of a dict, end the parsing here
        if line == '}':
            return

        # Ignore lines that aren't key-value pairs
        if ' = ' not in line:
            continue
        
        # Split the key-value pairs into two tokens
        ltoken, rtoken = line.split(' = ')

        # Remove the leading and trailing `["` from the keys
        key = ltoken[2:-2]

        # If it's the start of a nested sub-dictionary,
        if rtoken == '{':
            # Call the function again with the same iterator
            subdata = {}
            parse(iterator, subdata)
            data[key] = subdata

        else:
            # Else, use the same dictionary
            data[key] = rtoken
```

Usage:

```
t = """{
    ["gradient"] = true,
    ["dark"] = true,
    ["sky"] = false,
    ["rainbow"] = false,
    ["settings"] = {
        ["size"] = 100,
        ["smooth"] = true,
        ["dev"] = {
            ["inspect"] = "F1"
        }
        ["logo_size"] = 600
    },
    ["jokes"] = false,
}"""

import pprint

data = {}
parse(iter(t.split('\n')), data)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

It outputs

```
{'dark': 'true',
 'gradient': 'true',
 'jokes': 'false',
 'rainbow': 'false',
 'settings': {'dev': {'inspect': '"F1"'},
              'logo_size': '600',
              'size': '100',
              'smooth': 'true'},
 'sky': 'false'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark), you can easily create a robust and easy to understand parser:

```
from lark import Lark, v_args, Transformer

@v_args(inline=True)
class ToDict(Transformer):
    def start(self, data):
        return data

    def dictionary(self, *pairs):
        return dict(pairs)

    def key_pair(self, key, value):
        return (self.string(key), value)

    true = staticmethod(lambda: True)
    false = staticmethod(lambda: False)

    def number(self, token):
        try:
            return int(token)
        except ValueError:
            return float(token)

    def string(self, token):
        # Safe in this case, since we can trust that ESCAPED_STRING doesn't match something dangerous
        return eval(token)


parser = Lark(r"""
start: "return" value

value: "{" key_pair (","? key_pair)* ","? "}" -> dictionary
     | "true" -> true
     | "false" -> false
     | (SIGNED_NUMBER|NUMBER) -> number
     | ESCAPED_STRING -> string

key_pair: "[" ESCAPED_STRING "]" "=" value

%import common.ESCAPED_STRING
%import common (NUMBER, SIGNED_NUMBER)

%ignore /\s+/
""", parser="lalr", transformer=ToDict())
```

`parser.parse(text)` will give you a dictionary of the content.

Answer (score 0):

How about to convert it to JSON style and use JSON library?

```
import json

with open('file.ini') as f:
    my_data = f.read()

print(my_data)

# Replace custom syntax with valid JSON syntax
json_like_data = my_data.replace('["', '"') .replace('"]', '"').replace("return ", "").replace("=", ":").replace("return", "")
print(json_like_data)

# Parse the JSON-like data
data = json.loads(json_like_data)

# Now 'data' is a Python dictionary with the parsed data
print(data)
```

I have corrected commas in your file to one style so it make more sense

```
return {
    ["gradient"] = true,
    ["dark"] = true,
    ["sky"] = false,
    ["rainbow"] = false,
    ["settings"] = {
        ["size"] = 100,
        ["smooth"] = true,
        ["dev"] = {
            ["inspect"] = "F1"
        },
        ["logo_size"] = 600
    },
    ["jokes"] = false
}
```

The output

```
{'gradient': True, 'dark': True, 'sky': False, 'rainbow': False, 'settings': {'size': 100, 'smooth': True, 'dev': {'inspect': 'F1'}, 'logo_size': 600}, 'jokes': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me you aproach works, you just need to undertand why this data type would not generate valid jsons.

a code similiar to this should work, for better haddling change to regex:

Remove the wrong commas, and make sure close bracks inside have comma.

The brack before F1, has no comma.
The last key has a comma, but it is the last data.

```py
import json

data_str  = """return {
    ["gradient"] = true,
    ["dark"] = true,
    ["sky"] = false,
    ["rainbow"] = false,
    ["settings"] = {
        ["size"] = 100,
        ["smooth"] = true,
        ["dev"] = {
            ["inspect"] = "F1"
        }
        ["logo_size"] = 600
    },
    ["jokes"] = false,
}"""

data_str = data_str.replace('["', '"') .replace('"]', '"').replace("return ", "").replace("=", ":")
data_str = data_str.strip("{}")
data_str = data_str.strip(" \n,")
data_str = data_str.replace('},', '}')
data_str = data_str.replace('}', '},')
data_str = "{\n"+data_str+"\n}"
json.loads(data_str)
```

with regex you could easily handle data line

```py
import json
import re

data_str = """return {
    ["gradient"] = true,
    ["dark"] = true,
    ["sky"] = false,
    ["rainbow"] = false,
    ["settings"] = {
        ["size"] = 100,
        ["smooth"] = true,
        ["dev"] = {
            ["inspect"] = "F1",
            ["wrongdata"] = true,
        },
        ["logo_size"] = 600
    },
    ["jokes"] = false,
}"""

# Replace specific patterns using regex
data_str = re.sub(r'\[(\w+)\]\s*=\s*(\w+)', r'"\1": \2', data_str)  # Convert ["key"] = value to "key": value
data_str = re.sub(r',(\s*[}\]])', r'\1', data_str)  # Remove trailing commas before closing braces or brackets
data_str = re.sub(r',(\s*[,}\]])', r'\1', data_str)  # Remove trailing commas before a new element in the structure

# Perform other replacements as needed
data_str = data_str.replace('["', '"').replace('"]', '"').replace("return ", "").replace("=", ":")
data_str = data_str.strip("{}")
data_str = data_str.strip(" \n,")

# Add necessary commas and braces
data_str = "{\n" + data_str + "\n}"

# Load the JSON data
json_data = json.loads(data_str)
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=2))
```

answer

```py
{
  "gradient": true,
  "dark": true,
  "sky": false,
  "rainbow": false,
  "settings": {
    "size": 100,
    "smooth": true,
    "dev": {
      "inspect": "F1",
      "wrongdata": true
    },
    "logo_size": 600
  },
  "jokes": false
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of the case of wrong commas in the struct, but i regex could handle it easily too (imagine "inspect": "F1", without comma, it would make an invalid json).